# How to set color array into another color arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, arrays

My below Codes gives me error:"Index was outside the bounds of the array." My Algorithms create Colorset arrays that's arrays dimention '16',
But i need Second one 'colorSetLegend' that's dimensions:32 if you look below Bold codes that returns me error.

```
 Color[] colorSetLegend = new Color[32];
            Color[] colorSet = { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Yellow };
            Color end = Color.White;
            colorSet = ColorMaker.GenerateColor(colorSet, end);

            for (int i = 0; i < colorSet.Length; )
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < colorSetLegend.Length; )
                {
                    colorSetLegend[j] = colorSet[i];
                    colorSetLegend[j++] = Color.Black;
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

My Color generator below:

```
public class ColorMaker
{
    public static Color[] GenerateColor(Color[] baseColorSet, Color end)
    {
        Color[] colorSet = new Color[16];
        int j = 0;
        foreach (Color start in baseColorSet)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i += 4)
            {
                int r = Interpolate(start.R, end.R, 15, i),
                    g = Interpolate(start.G, end.G, 15, i),
                    b = Interpolate(start.B, end.B, 15, i);

                colorSet[j] = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                j++;
            }
        }

        return colorSet;

    }
    static int Interpolate(int start, int end, int steps, int count)
    {
        float s = start, e = end, final = s + (((e - s) / steps) * count);
        return (int)final;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incrementing i in your *inner* loop. I suspect you meant to do it in your *outer* loop - otherwise during *one* iteration of your outer loop, you're incrementing `i` many times, until you exceed the bounds of the array.

Alternatively, you could write your `for` loops the same way everyone else does:

```
for (int i = 0; i < colorSet.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colorSetLegend.Length; j++)
    {
        colorSetLegend[j] = colorSet[i];
        colorSetLegend[j] = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Having said that, the code's a bit pointless given that the first line inside the loop sets `colorSetLegend[j]` and the second line sets the same element again. Furthermore, on the next iteration of the outer loop you'll be overwriting all the values in `colorSetLegend` all over again. What are you trying to accomplish?

Marc made a good-looking guess at your aim here (although he's now deleted his answer!)

Here's his guess at working code for what you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < colorSet.Length; i++)
{
    colorSetLegend[i*2] = colorSet[i];
    colorSetLegend[(i*2)+1] = Color.Black;
}
```

A few things to learn from this, if he's right:

- Think about the level of nesting of your loops. Did you really mean to have two loops here?
- Try to use conventional idioms for looping - whenever I see an empty bit at the end of the start of a `for` loop, I get nervous
- Using pre- and post-increment operators in another expression is easy to get wrong.

Comment: ForExample;
colorSetLegend[0] = "Red";
colorSetLegend[1] = Color.Black;
colorSetLegend[2] = "FireBrick";
colorSetLegend[3] = Color.Black;

Comment: Sounds like Marc's guess was right then. Have a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you are looking for:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < colorSet.Length; i++)
{
    colorSetLegend[j++] = colorSet[i];
    colorSetLegend[j++] = Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: That will work, yes - but I prefer Marc's answer (now copied into mine) as it doesn't use pre/post-increment within a statement. That always makes me stop and check that it really is doing what I need it to - and anything that harms readability should be avoided where possible, IMO.